# Plotting some maths illustrations in LaTeX

Tags: tikz-pgf, pgfplots

I'm relatively new to LaTeX and I'd like to know how can I generate this graph in LaTeX? Do you recommend any software in particular? [image]

Thanks in advance.

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX!](//tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1436) On this site, a question should typically revolve around an abstract issue (e.g. "How do I get a double horizontal line in a table?") rather than a concrete application (e.g. "How do I make this table?"). Questions that look like "Please do this complicated thing for me" tend to get closed because they are either "off topic", "too broad", or "unclear". Please try to make your question clear and simple by giving a [minimal working example (MWE)](//tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/228): you'll stand a greater chance of getting help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is perhaps easiest to draw this with Ti*k*Z.

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{calc}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
 \coordinate (O) at (0,0); 
 \draw[-latex] (O) -- (8,0);
 \draw[-latex] (O) -- (0,4);
 \coordinate[label=left:$P$] (P) at (1,0.2);
 \coordinate[label=right:$Q$] (Q) at (7.5,3.6);
 \draw[blue,-latex] (P) -- (Q);
 \draw plot[domain=1:7.5,variable=\x] ({1+6.5*(1-cos((\x-1)*(90/6.5)))},
 {0.2+3.4*sin((\x-1)*(90/6.5))}); 
 \draw[red,-latex] ({1+6.5*(1-cos((4-1)*(90/6.5)))},
 {0.2+3.4*sin((4-1)*(90/6.5)}) --++(2,1.1) node[midway,above,black]{$v$};
 \draw[dotted] ({1+6.5*(1-cos((4-1)*(90/6.5)))},
 {0.2+3.4*sin((4-1)*(90/6.5)}) -- ++(2,0)-- ++(0,1.1);
 \coordinate (v) at (4,3.4);
 \draw[dotted] (O-|P)node[below]{$f(a)$} -- (P) -- (O|-P)node[left]{$g(b)$};
 \draw[dotted] (O-|Q)node[below]{$f(b)$} -- 
 node[pos=0.3,left]{$\displaystyle \frac{g'(c)}{f'(c)}=
 \frac{g(b)-g(a)}{f(b)-f(a)}$} (Q) -- (O|-Q)node[left]{$g(a)$};
 \draw[dotted] (O|-P) -- (P-|Q);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Think of this as a kind of welcome present, and follow Stefan Pinnow's advices when posting your next question.

Comment: Thanks a lot! I apologise for posting a question that concrete but I still don't know how to work with TikZ. Next time, I'll keep in mind Stefan Pinnow's advices.